# What is the correct error class to be used to capture all exceptions for CreateFromDocument in pyxb

Tags: python, exception, pyxb

How to capture all possible pyxb exceptions for CreateFromDocument(input_xml).
Example:

```
try:
    py_obj = CreateFromDocument(input_xml)
except pyxb.UnrecognizedContentError as e:
    raise e
```

Here it captures only UnrecognizedContentError. But I want to capture all possible errors when I use CreateFromDocument. What is the correct Error class should I use from pyxb?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to catch *all* possible exceptions is to catch the base `Exception` type - but that's not something you want to do. You just want to make sure you *only* catch the exceptions *you can handle at this point in your code* anyway... If you want to know which exceptions this call is most likely to raise, the doc and source code should tell you.

Answer (score 1):

The exception hierarchy for PyXB is described in the [user reference](http://pyxb.sourceforge.net/userref_validating.html#runtime-exception-hierarchy) which may be out of date, and the [API](http://pyxb.sourceforge.net/api/pyxb.exceptions_.PyXBException-class.html) which should be current for its release.  [pyxb.ValidationError](http://pyxb.sourceforge.net/userref_validating.html#runtime-exception-hierarchy) is most likely to catch everything of interest that arises from CreateFromDocument.  [Debugging Validation Errors](http://pyxb.sourceforge.net/userref_validating.html) may be helpful for recovery from exceptions.